# Preventing a height change when adding a border with box-sizing

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to find something that describes this issue, but if I'm missing it, just let me know.

Below is a demo (Tested in IE11 and Chrome) which shows the problem perfectly

Essentially, I'm trying to add a border to an element, and keep the size the same. It's working perfectly for the width, but the height, it only accommodates half of it, so I have an extra 3px in height.

Is there a way to prevent this / get around it without using a script? I can make changes specifically to the element(s) which have the border, but **I don't know the actual height (200px is used here just for demo purposes**, so simply reducing the height isn't an option.

Thanks.

EDIT (Since apparently it's unclear what I'm asking)

### ***Is there a way to prevent the height changing without using a script?***

DEMO:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
div img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.div {
  border: 3px dotted blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="div">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="div" style="clear:left">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: My usual workaround is to add border with same color as the background prior to the action.

Comment: Did you try to assign `border: 3px dotted blue;` for `div img` instead of `div`?

Comment: You've not specified the hight of div

Comment: @Aravind, I'm creating a visual distinction, so I want the size of the image to change.

Comment: @Banzay, Yes, it makes it worse: http://jsfiddle.net/kdxd792w/4/

Comment: is it a solution?: http://jsfiddle.net/nj8vegxf/

Comment: @Banzay, it appears to be, though Vitorino gave a shorter solution. If you want to put it into an answer, I'll gladly vote it up.

Comment: My solution is shorter by 2 lines :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set add `line-height:0px` if there is no text for `.div` as image is `inline-block` element it add whitespace

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
div img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.div {
  border: 3px dotted blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="div">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="div" style="clear:left">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks. I think the spec should say `line-height` is zero if there's no text by default. :)

Answer (score 1):

Either add the line-height attribute to the `div` as @Vitorino suggested or add  `vertical-align: middle` to the `img`. Both will fix the whitespace issue for an `inline-block`

```css
div img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.div {
  border: 3px dotted blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant of solution:

```
div {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:3px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.div img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:3px dotted blue;
}
```