# Border not change size of text

Tags: html, css

Alrighty, so I'm using this to make myself a header when a user hovers over the tab it'll show a line. I'm trying to do this without it changing the size when a user hovers over it. I want a line to appear but nothing else should happen.

Here is a fiddle,
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fuz5pbo2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-tab">
    <div class="center-vertical">
      Main
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header-tab{
  height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
  padding:0 1vw 0 1vw;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:450;
  color:white;
}

.header-tab:hover{
  color:#ff704d;
  background:gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom:3px solid #ff704d;
}

.center-vertical{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%; 
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.header{
  height:5vw;
  background:black;
}

body{
  margin:0;
}
```

I think that it's because of the vertical center, but I'm quite unsure.
Thanks!

Edit: I don't want it to like, jump up.

Comment: Whatsup with the downvote :/?

Comment: This question has been asked many times. Basically, add a transparent border in the non-hover state and change the color in the `:hover` state.

Comment: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625812/css-hover-border-makes-inline-elements-adjust-slightly), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648342/preventing-a-height-change-when-adding-a-border-with-box-sizing), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612758/add-a-css-border-on-hover-without-moving-the-element), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254587/when-1-px-border-is-added-to-div-div-size-increases-dont-want-to-do-that)... [Search](http://stackoverflow.com/search) and [research](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu didn't really know what to search to achieve this result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `box-shadow` CSS property instead of `border-bottom`. Honestly, I think it makes quite a nice result for what you want to achieve.

```css
.header-tab:hover{
  color:#ff704d;
  background:gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 #ff704d;
}
```

**Hint:** I see that you're using `height` to define the menu's overall height. I recommend you to use the `.header-tab` padding to adjust the height. This way, you won't even need to vertical align anything.

I've edited your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fuz5pbo2/5/) so you can see it.

Comment: the point is, I'm using vw/percentages to define my footer and header and main, my page is unscrollable so I am nearly forced to work with a static height.

Comment: anyways, seems to be working just fine, thank you, I really didn't know how I'd search for this question.

Comment: I think both approaches could work well, but mine would demand a little more math. Still, I'm glad that it works. As a reference, I suggest you find some real website menus to take as an example, and inspect them with your browser's devtools. Might really come in handy!

Comment: This is a good solution. You and I were typing at the same time. Very elegant use of existing styles.

Answer (score 1):

First I need to say, all of these answers are true. However, I think the easiest solution is to use a background gradient instead of a background color. Sub this in for your hover state. It's also responsive and will adjust with your vw.

```css
.header-tab:hover{
  color:#ff704d;
  background: #b7b7b7;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, gray 0%, gray 93%, #ff704d 99%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, gray 0%, gray 93%, #ff704d 99%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, gray 0%, gray 93%, #ff704d 99%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on there. now it is not jumping up.

https://jsfiddle.net/bizedkhan/pbxy32kq

```
.header-tab{
height:100%;
display:inline-block;
padding:0 1vw 0 1vw;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:450;
color:white;
border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
box-sizing: border-box;
transition: all .5s
}
.header-tab:hover{
color:#ff704d;
background:gray;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-bottom:3px solid #ff704d;
}
.center-vertical{
position: relative;
top: 50%; 
transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.header{
height:5vw;
background:black;
}
body{
 margin:0;
}
```